# Running Sonar from Maven: SQL driver not found

Tags: maven, sonarqube

When I try to start `mvn sonar:sonar` I get an "SQL driver not found"

> sorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
>           ... 30 more
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL driver not found org.h2.Driver
>           at  org.sonar.api.database.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:87)
>           at org.sonar.api.database.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(Abstr
>   actDatabaseConnector.java:178)
>           ... 36 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
>           at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:627)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>           at org.sonar.api.database.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDa
>   tabaseConnector.java:83)
>           ... 37 more

Does anybody know what could be the cause and/or solution?

Update:

Sonar.properties is the default, as is
Maven Settings

```
    <profile>
        <id>sonar</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</sonar.jdbc.driverClassName>
            <sonar.jdbc.url>jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar</sonar.jdbc.url>  

            <!-- optional URL to server. Default value is http://localhost:9000 -->
            <sonar.host.url>
              http://localhost:9000
            </sonar.host.url>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: What does your `sonar.properties` look like?

Comment: Please look at  http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven You should configure the `settings.xml` file, located in `$MAVEN_HOME/conf` or `~/.m2`

Comment: What version of Sonar are you using? Have you tried running with mvn -X?

Answer (score 1):

Derby is not used any longer by Sonar. You should install a newer version of Sonar (if possible the latest 3.5) and clean up your configuration, mainly all the "sonar.jdbc.*" properties.

Comment: Hey Fabrice, thanks for thinking along! The issue is with version 3.5.1, a clean install (I have no clue why it still tries to use the Derby driver, maybe some parent pom issue?). But anyway, if I change the settings to org.h2.Driver, the issue remains...

Answer (score 1):

You may have to play with the dependency version to match your (Sonar's?) H2 database, but try adding the following dependency to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.171</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This should make the class available for the Sonar plugin to use during your build, but not include it in your artifacts.

Comment: Thanks. But still "Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.h2.Driver". The weird thing is that it *does* work when I run the standalone Sonar Runner, so H2 in itself works just fine.